# Como usar una imagen como submit?

Tags: php, html, imagen, submit

Quisiera saber como utilizar una imagen como submit ya que no me deja de la forma en que lo estoy utilizando y al utilizar una type="image" me genera un error en la parte de php espero y me puedan ayudar.

```html
<?php
$usb_comPort = "COM3";
 if ($_POST['btn']) {
  exec("ECHO 1 > $usb_comPort");
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Boton Peatonal</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="icono.png">
</head>
<body>
 <form  method="post" action="">
  <input type='submit' name='btn' value="" src="boton.png" style='width:300px; height:130px' >
  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código PHP que te genera error y el mensaje de error que te genera? En ese código no veo por ningún lado el `type="image"` y la forma en la que usas la imagen no entiendo por qué dices que "no me deja". ¿Qué es lo que tratas de conseguir?

Answer (score 8):

El atributo `src` es propio de las etiquetas `<img>`, por lo que otros elementos no lo admiten. Lo que podrías hacer es darle un `background-image` al botón.

```css
#enviar {
  background-image: url('https://ep00.epimg.net/tecnologia/imagenes/2015/06/25/actualidad/1435248518_445335_1435251285_noticia_normal.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Boton Peatonal</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="icono.png">
</head>
<body>
 <form  method="post" action="">
  <input id="enviar" type='submit' name='btn' value="" style='width:300px; height:130px'>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solo por aportar un poquito de usabilidad a la respuesta, que es perfectamente válida de @phpMyGuel, le añadiría a ese input un 'cursor:pointer' para que sea claramente identificado como una botón o bien cambiaría directamente el input por un button:

**css**

```
#enviar {
      background-image: url('https://www.royalcanin.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/11.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: orange;
      cursor: pointer;
      width:300px; 
      height:130px;
    }

#enviar2 {
  background-image: url('https://www.royalcanin.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/11.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  width:300px; 
  height:130px;
}
```

**forms html**

```
<form  method="post" action="">
    <input id="enviar" type='submit' name='btn' value="">
</form>
<form  method="post" action="">
    <button id="enviar2" name='btn' value="">&nbsp;</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta función es la que enviara el POST onclick en la imagen

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Submit con Imagen</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     body {
     background-color: #9CC;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
    function enviar(destino)   // esta es la funcion 
     { 
    document.form1.action = destino;
    document.form1.submit()
    }
    </script>
```

abrimos formulario
//dejo vacío action

```
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Escriba mensaje</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

input  ingresar texto

```
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="eliminar" type="text"/></td>
```

input imagen debes poner una imagen y reemplazar los datos y la ubicacion

```
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input  type="image"src="images/cruz-eliminar.gif" 
    width="15" height="15" onclick="enviar" /></td> // aquí se ejecuta la función
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

lo siguiente lo puse para verificar el envío submit imprimiendo el $_POST si existe y no esta vacio

```
    <?php if (isset($_POST['eliminar'])&&($_POST['eliminar']!="")){ echo "Texto 
    Enviado= ".$_POST['eliminar'];} elseif (isset($_POST['eliminar'])&& 
    ($_POST['eliminar']=="")) echo "Nada Enviado"?>
    </body>
    </html>
```